# How do I animate a <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am trying to keep the `<div>` centered on the screen but this fails.

Here is the code:

```
var self = $(this);
self.animate({
    'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - (self.outerHeight() / 2),
    'left': ($(window).width() / 2) - (self.outerWidth() / 2)
}, 600, 'swing', function () {
    self.animate({
        'width': '+=200px',
        'height': '+=200px', 
        'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - (self.outerHeight() / 2), //NO UPDATE
        'left': ($(window).width() / 2) - (self.outerWidth() / 2) //NO UPDATE
    }, 600, 'linear');
});
```

So mainly after the second animation where the `<div>` grows by 200px on each direction, top and left stay the same from the first animation. I'd like the position to update as well.

What can be done here?

Comment: Check the value the of outerHeight and outerWidth.  I don't think these values are being updated with the +200px until after the animate has finished.  Therefore to get the correct calculation you may too need do `($(window).height() / 2) - ((self.outerHeight() + 200) / 2 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do take into consideration than when running the following code:

```
'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - (self.outerHeight() / 2), //NO UPDATE
'left': ($(window).width() / 2) - (self.outerWidth() / 2) //NO UPDATE
```

The value you get from `self.outerHeight()` is the absolute current value (without the added amount) as jQuery will increment the size slowly to give the impression of an animation.

To make it work you **must add** the amount manually:

```
'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - ((self.outerHeight()+200) / 2), // notice the +200
```

Comment: thanks, actually +200 isn't returning it exactly to the middle but a bit sided to the left. What could be causing this?

Comment: @user1027620 I only gave you the `top` example... I'd assume you wrote the left by your own... correct?

Comment: Can you provide a functional example with your problem on JsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your second animation is all executing at the same time, so self.outerHeight() is equal to the outerheight at the time of execution, not when the animation of width/height is done.

You should probably set it to:

```
self.animate({
            'width': '+=200px',
            'height': '+=200px', 
            'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - ((self.outerHeight() +200 )/ 2), //NO UPDATE
            'left': ($(window).width() / 2) - ((self.outerWidth() +200 )/ 2) //NO UPDATE
        }, 600, 'linear');
```